# html table max row and ajax navigation

Tags: ajax, navigation, html-table

I have a PHP page that returns an HTML table like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>First Row data</td><td>Second Row  data</td><td>Third Row  data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>First Row data</td><td>Second Row  data</td><td>Third Row  data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>First Row data</td><td>Second Row  data</td><td>Third Row  data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>etc...</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to do is to add an ajax numerical pagination system (1  2 ... 6) that allows we to fix a max 3 rows to display and reaching the others with the navigation.

Do you know where can I find a ready script that can help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this about what your looking for? 
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxpaginate/index.htm

Comment: It's not really a ready script, but this can help you build it in jQuery.
http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/jquery/jquery-javascript-pagination.html